# Override sinatra routes set in a gem

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Sinatra along with the Sinatra-authentication gem to build a site.

I would like to override some of the logic one of the routes, but not sure of the best way to approach it.

Comment: you might consider adding the versions of the gems you are using, for anyone reading this in future.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes)

> Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that matches the request is invoked.

So, for example, if you wanted to override the logic in the "/logged_in" route you could do:

```
get "/logged_in" do
  # your code here
end

register Sinatra::Authentication
```

and your route would be compiled first and the one defined in sinatra-authentication would not be called.

Comment: This might work if I were to change my app to run as a Sinatra Modular app, but I currently have it running as a Sinatra Classic app and didn't really want to convert it.

Comment: ok, but it's something like 4 lines of code to convert...